# Why am I getting different values if I change my 'elif' statement to 'if'?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, line

I have a code where I am trying to compare hydrophilic and hydrophobic interactions. My categories are 'Hydrophilic', 'Hydrophobic' and 'Other'. Every time I try to find out how many of each interaction category there is, I always get always get "Other:0" regardless of how many there should actually be. I know that every file I've tested has plenty of interactions that should be in 'Other'.

I've used an almost identical code successfully for a different project and can't work out what's different now. I have also made sure all the line spacing and indentation is perfect and it still has this problem :(

I tried:

```
Hydrophilic = 0
Hydrophobic = 0
Other = 0

with open(filename) as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
      for line in lines:
         values = line.split(",")
      
         if values[1] == "HYDROPHOBIC":
            Hydrophobic += 1
         elif values[1] == "HBOND" or "WEAK_HBOND" or "POLAR" or "WEAK_POLAR":
            Hydrophilic += 1
         else:
            Other += 1

sizes = {'Hydrophilic':Hydrophilic, 'Hydrophobic':Hydrophobic, 'Other':Other}

print(sizes)
```

and was hoping for it to print something along the lines of (Hydrophilic:7, Hydrophobic:4, Other:13) but always get Other:0.

I tried replacing 'elif' for 'if' and got different numbers for hydrophobic and hydrophilic (still 0 for other). I tried swapping the order so that the hydrophilic values are added first and ended up with 0 hydrophobic and 0 other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it happens?

`elif values[1] == "HBOND" or "WEAK_HBOND" or "POLAR" or "WEAK_POLAR":`

When you put `or`, it assumes that it's a completely different condition. So, it checks if `values[1]` is `"HBOND"`. If it fails, it goes to the next condition, which is **just `"WEAK_HBOND"`**. Since there's no equation sign, **Python tries to turn the string into a boolean**.

String turns into `False` if it's empty and into `True` if it's not empty. Since `"HBOND"` is not an empty string, it turns into `True` and the `elif` block (or the `if` block if you changed it) gets executed, and the `else` block does not work.

### Why the value changes when swapping `elif` to `if`?

#### When you use `if` both times

This condition gets executed: (assuming it's true):
`if values[1] == "HYDROPHOBIC":`
Python goes to the next condition:
`if values[1] == "HBOND" or "WEAK_HBOND" or "POLAR" or "WEAK_POLAR":`
It sees `if`, so it checks the condition.
If `values[1] == "HBOND"` is true, it executes.
If it's *not* true, then it goes to the next one.
`"WEAK_HBOND"`
It sees a string. Since there's no equation (`==`), **it turns the string into boolean** and executes the condition.
So, on one iteration, it added `1` to both `Hydrophobic` and `Hydrophilic` variables.

### When you use `elif`

This condition gets executed: (assuming it's true):
`if values[1] == "HYDROPHOBIC":`
Python goes to the next line:
`elif values[1] == "HBOND" or "WEAK_HBOND" or "POLAR" or "WEAK_POLAR":`
It sees `elif`, so it checks the **previous condition** associated with the `elif` block. **It was the previous `if`** which was true, so it **will skip it anyways**. It won't increase the `Hydrophilic` value if the `if` condition before (`values[1] == "HYDROPHOBIC"`) was true.

### What about the `else` part?

`else` never gets executed in the both cases anyways.
When you are using `elif`, it just either executes the `elif` or the previous `if` block, skipping the `else` block.
If you use `if` in both cases, as I explained before, Python turns the `"HBOND"` string into a boolean, and assumes that the `if` block (second one) **is true, not executing the `else` block**.

## How to fix it?

There are multiple options:

1. Group your strings into an array and use the `in` operator:
   `elif values[1] in ["HBOND", "WEAK_HBOND", "POLAR", "WEAK_POLAR"]:`
2. Write the == sign for every single string out there:
   `elif values[1] == "HBOND" or values[1] == "WEAK_HBOND" or values[1] == "POLAR" or values[1] == "WEAK_POLAR":`
   *Notice how I typed out `values[1] ==`  after `or` every single time, so that Python knows I'm comparing values[1] and instead of turning it into a boolean it does the equation (`==`)*

In both cases, use `elif` instead of `if` for the second condition (`elif values[1] == ...`)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly as soon as I turned the 'or' statements into an array.